# Is this matter? ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed

Tags: pip, pytorch, conda

I have cuda 12 and in a fresh conda environment with python 3.11 I ran `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118`

However, it shows:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires bleach, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires defusedxml, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires jupyter-core>=4.7, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires nbformat>=5.1, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires packaging, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires pandocfilters>=1.4.1, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires pygments>=2.4.1, which is not installed.
nbconvert 7.4.0 requires traitlets>=5.0, which is not installed.
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.2 certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 filelock-3.9.0 idna-3.4 jinja2-3.1.2 mpmath-1.2.1 networkx-3.0 numpy-1.24.1 pillow-9.3.0 requests-2.28.1 sympy-1.11.1 torch-2.0.1+cu118 torchaudio-2.0.2+cu118 torchvision-0.15.2+cu118 typing-extensions-4.4.0 urllib3-1.26.13
```

Is this important? If so, how can I fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is related to incomplete package dependencies. It’s important to address this because, in some cases, missing dependencies can cause issues with the installed packages and their functionality.

To address this issue, I recommend running the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

This command will upgrade pip to the latest version, which may help to resolve any dependency issues. Afterward, you can try installing PyTorch again using the command you mentioned previously:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

If you still see the same error message, you can try installing the missing dependencies manually using pip. For example:

```
pip3 install jupyter-core nbformat traitlets packaging pandocfilters bleach pygments defusedxml
```

Once all the package dependencies have been installed, you can try installing PyTorch again. I hope this helps!